# In Python, how can you respond to method calls that don't exist on an object?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic Finders and Method Missing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913020/dynamic-finders-and-method-missing-in-python)

I know you can do this in Ruby, but how would it be done in Python?

So basically you could maybe to a regex on the method call that didn't exist, and create 'syntactic sugar'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913020/dynamic-finders-and-method-missing-in-python

Comment: @ameer: Thanks for finding that. Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[Define `__getattr__`.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)

But that still won't make `s./.*/` valid syntax, if that's what you have in mind. Python's syntax is nowhere as bendable as Ruby's.

Comment: really? I for some reason thought it would be very very similiar

Comment: You can't *add* to Python's syntax.  Nonstandard syntax sugar is mostly good for preventing other people from understanding your code.

Comment: @Blankman: No. Python wants to be simple and not Perl-like, so its grammar is mich simpler than Ruby's.

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) on an object to handle requests for attributes that do not exist. This only works for new-style classes. If you have old-style classes, you can use [delnans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145844/in-python-how-can-you-respond-to-method-calls-that-dont-exist-on-an-object/4145872#4145872).

Comment: Terminology nitpicking: There is no overloading (as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading) in Python or in Ruby. Only overriding.

Comment: `__getattribute__` is called on *all* attribute lookups.  delnan's answer is correct for both new and old-style classes.

Comment: You confused me :) I thought that (correctly, as @Glenn suggests and the docs confirm) that `__getattr__` is called for missing attributes/methods (as the question asks) while `__getattribute__` is used *always* when defined.