# Ruby’s “method_missing” in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, method-missing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python equivalent of Ruby's 'method_missing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704151/python-equivalent-of-rubys-method-missing)

Is there any technique available in Python for intercepting messages (method calls) like the method_missing technique in Ruby?

Comment: Can you please describe the exact mechanism you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to implement something like Rails dynamic-finders in Python.

Comment: @Zeck, I mean, can you please explain what are you looking for, for non-Ruby people?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As others have mentioned, in Python, when you execute `o.f(x)`, it's really a two-step operation: First, get the `f` attribute of `o`, then call it with parameter `x`.  It's the first step that fails because there is no attribute `f`, and it's that step that invokes the Python magic method `__getattr__`.

So you have to implement `__getattr__`, and what it returns must be callable.  Keep in mind, if you also try to get `o.some_data_that_doesnt_exist`, the same `__getattr__` will be called, and it won't know that it's a "data" attribute vs. a "method" that being sought.

Here's an example of returning a callable:

```
class MyRubylikeThing(object):
    #...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def _missing(*args, **kwargs):
            print "A missing method was called."
            print "The object was %r, the method was %r. " % (self, name)
            print "It was called with %r and %r as arguments" % (args, kwargs)
        return _missing

r = MyRubylikeThing()
r.hello("there", "world", also="bye")
```

produces:

```
A missing method was called.
The object was <__main__.MyRubylikeThing object at 0x01FA5940>, the method was 'hello'.
It was called with ('there', 'world') and {'also': 'bye'} as arguments
```

Comment: This could only cover the missing method. What if I want to cover missing member and method?   "def __getattr__(self, name)", the name attribute is only a string, which is not enough to tell me if this atrribute with this name is a method, or a member.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload `__getattr__` and return a callable from that. Note that you can NOT decide during attribute lookup whether the requested attribute is intended to be called, since Python does that in two steps.

Comment: Thank you guys. I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913020/dynamic-finders-and-method-missing-in-python/913438#913438). But I'm just wondering how to get passing parameters?