# How to catch any method called on an object in python?

Tags: python, oop, object, methods, call

I'm looking for a pythonic solution on how to store a method which is called on an object right inside the object.

Because in python, if I want to catch for example the `abs()` method, I will overload this operator like:

```
Catcher(object):
    def __abs__(self):
        self.function = abs

c = Catcher()
abs(c)  # Now c.function stores 'abs' as it was called on c
```

If I want to catch a function, which have an other attribute in it, for example `pow()`, I'm going to use this:

```
Catcher(object):
    def __pow__(self, value):
        self.function = pow
        self.value = value

c = Catcher()
c ** 2  # Now c.function stores 'pow', and c.value stores '2'
```

Now, what I'm looking for is a general solution, to catch and store any kind of function called on `Catcher`, without implementing all overloads, and other cases. And as You can see, I also want to store the values (*maybe in a list, if there is more than one of them?*) which are the attributes of a method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about functions that don't delegate to a dunder method?

Comment: You might wanna look into class decorators and metaclasses.

Comment: @delnan I guess, those are also OK, because in my case, these functions are looking for something else, a value or a method to call.

Comment: @morphyn could you be more specific? AFAIK metaclasses are good for class-object creation, aren't they?

Comment: One way is to have a decorator on each method that will register the calls. A class decorator will allow you to automatically apply a decorator on each method. You could also do that with a metaclass but I guess it would be more complicated.

Comment: Can't you override `__getattr__` and check that the attribute being accessed is a method?

Comment: @poorsod: No, I tried that approach. Dunder hooks are looked up on the *class*, not the instance, so a metaclass is then required. But `__getattr__` doesn't seem to be used in that case. Neither does `__getattribute__`.

Comment: The answer might be there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954116/rubys-method-missing-in-python

Comment: Related: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/366254-generic-proxy-object-with-beforeafter-method-hooks/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A metaclass won't help here; although special methods are looked up on the type of the current object (so the class for instances), `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` are not consulted when doing so (probably because they are themselves special methods). So to catch *all* dunder methods, you are forced to create them all.

You can get a pretty decent list of all *operator* special methods (`__pow__`, `__gt__`, etc.) by enumerating the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
operator_hooks = [name for name in dir(operator) if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')]
```

Armed with that list a class decorator could be:

```
def instrument_operator_hooks(cls):
    def add_hook(name):
        operator_func = getattr(operator, name.strip('_'), None)
        existing = getattr(cls, name, None)

        def op_hook(self, *args, **kw):
            print "Hooking into {}".format(name)
            self._function = operator_func
            self._params = (args, kw)
            if existing is not None:
                return existing(self, *args, **kw)
            raise AttributeError(name)

        try:
            setattr(cls, name, op_hook)
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            pass  # skip __name__ and __doc__ and the like

    for hook_name in operator_hooks:
        add_hook(hook_name)
    return cls
```

Then apply that to your class:

```
@instrument_operator_hooks
class CatchAll(object):
    pass
```

Demo:

```
>>> c = CatchAll()
>>> c ** 2
Hooking into __pow__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in op_hook
AttributeError: __pow__
>>> c._function
<built-in function pow>
>>> c._params
((2,), {})
```

So, even though our class doesn't define `__pow__` explicitly, we still hooked into it.

Comment: As I'm quite new to `@decorators`, I had to read this [article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808), which is amazingly straightforward, and then I just understood, what you did.. and I have to admit, now, that I know what is going on — it's not that kind of a magic anymore :):) I reimplemented your solution in a decorator-class — i guess, it's more easy to follow what is going on in my code.

Comment: @PeterVaro: That is quite alright. :-) The focus of my answer was how to generate a list of dunder-method names anyway. :-P

Answer (score 4):

This is a way to do it.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps
from collections import namedtuple

call = namedtuple('Call', ['fname', 'args', 'kwargs'])
calls = []

def register_calls(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f_call(*args, **kw):
        calls.append(call(f.__name__, args, kw))
        print calls
        return f(*args, **kw)
    return f_call


def decorate_methods(decorator):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
            setattr(cls, name, decorator(m))
        return cls
    return class_decorator


@decorate_methods(register_calls)
class Test(object):

    def test1(self):
        print 'test1'

    def test2(self):
        print 'test2'
```

Now all the calls to `test1` and `test2` will be registers in the `calls` `list`.

`decorate_methods` applies a decorator to each method of the class. `register_calls` registers the calls to the methods in `calls`, with the name of the function and the arguments.

Comment: But this still requires you to create *all* special methods on the class first.

Comment: @morphyn yes, Martijn Pieters is right, I've just tested this — maybe I'm not using it properly — but I can't do what I want with this...

Comment: Yes, you still need to create the methods. I did not understand what you wanted. You're looking for ruby's `method_missing` then :) You will have to use `__getattr__` then.