# Object that raises exception when used in any way

Tags: python, exception, python-3.4

I need to create an object that would raise a custom exception, `UnusableObjectError`, when it is used in any way (creating it should not create an exception though).

```
a = UnusableClass()     # No error
b = UnusableClass()     # No error
a == 4                  # Raises UnusableObjectError
'x' in a                # Raises UnusableObjectError
for i in a:             # Raises UnusableObjectError
    print(i)

# ..and so on
```

---

I came up with the code below which seems to behave as expected.

```
class UnusableObjectError(Exception):
    pass

CLASSES_WITH_MAGIC_METHODS = (str(), object, float(), dict())

# Combines all magic methods I can think of.
MAGIC_METHODS_TO_CHANGE = set()
for i in CLASSES_WITH_MAGIC_METHODS:
    MAGIC_METHODS_TO_CHANGE |= set(dir(i))
MAGIC_METHODS_TO_CHANGE.add('__call__')
# __init__ and __new__ must not raise an UnusableObjectError
# otherwise it would raise error even on creation of objects.
MAGIC_METHODS_TO_CHANGE -= {'__class__', '__init__', '__new__'}


def error_func(*args, **kwargs):
    """(nearly) all magic methods will be set to this function."""
    raise UnusableObjectError


class UnusableClass(object):
    pass

for i in MAGIC_METHODS_TO_CHANGE:
    setattr(UnusableClass, i, error_func)
```

<sub>(some improvements made, as suggested by [Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107660/duncan) in comments)</sub>

---

**Questions:**
Is there an already existing class that behaves as described?

If not, is there any flaw in my `UnusableClass()` (e.g., situations when using the instances of the class wouldn't raise an error) and if so, how can I fix those flaws?

Comment: Setting `__` methods on an instance won't generally work as you expect. You should define them directly on the class instead. Redefining `__getattribute__` to block access to any attribute other than the ones you want to permit would probably be a simpler way to do what you're attempting.

Comment: One example that won't work as you expect, try calling an instance: `a()` gives `TypeError: 'UnusableClass' object is not callable` because setting `__call__` on the instance is ignored. Likewise `a[1]=0`. Of course since these aren't implemented they will still throw an error just not your custom error.

Define on the class could be with `def` or just use `setattr` on the class rather than on the instance.

Comment: This also seems like a perfect use-case for metaclasses...

Comment: @thebjorn: Not really. This seems like a one-off thing, and creating a separate metaclass for a *single* class with a *single* object seems kinda excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out metaclasses and dunder (double underscore) methods don't go well together (which is unfortunate, since that would have been a more streamlined way to implement this).

I couldn't find any importable listing of magic method names, so I created one and put it on PyPi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/magicmethods/0.1.1). With it, the implementation of UnusableClass can be written as a simple class decorator:

```
import magicmethods

class UnusableObjectError(Exception): 
    pass

def unusable(cls):
    def _unusable(*args, **kwargs):
        raise UnusableObjectError()

    for name in set(magicmethods.all) - set(magicmethods.lifecycle):
        setattr(cls, name, _unusable)
    return cls

@unusable
class UnusableClass(object):
    pass
```

`magicmethods.lifecycle` contains `__new__`, `__init__`, and `__del__`. You might want to adjust this..

This implementation also handles:

```
a = UnusableClass()
with a:
    print 'oops'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__getattribute__` to block **all** access to attributes, *except special `__` attributes like `__contains__` or `__eq__` which are not catched by `__getattribute__`*, and use a `whitelist` to allow access to some methods:

```
class UnuseableClass(object):

    whitelist = ('alpha', 'echo',)

    def __init__(self):
        self.alpha = 42

    def echo(self, text):
        print text

    def not_callable(self):
        return 113

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in type(self).whitelist:
            return super(UnuseableClass, self).__getattribute__(name)
        else:
            raise Exception('Attribute is not useable: %s' % name)


unuseable_object = UnuseableClass()
print(unuseable_object.alpha)
unuseable_object.echo('calling echo')

try:
    unuseable_object.not_callable()
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc.message)
```

If you really need to catch even special method calls, you can use [How to catch any method called on an object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372229/how-to-catch-any-method-called-on-an-object-in-python).