# Implementing numbers.Real with minimal code

Tags: python, abc

I'm trying to create a class `MyFloat` that is very similar to `float` but has a `value` method and a few other methods. I also need instances of this class to interact with real `float`s and be "sticky" in the sense that `type(MyFloat(5) + 4)` is `MyFloat` and not `float`.

So this is what I have so far:

```py
class MyFloat(numbers.Real):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = float(value)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = float(value)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.value
```

but now I have to implement a ton of other methods in order to satisfy the abstract base class `numbers.Real` and also my requirement that this "acts" like a `float`. The issue is that a) there's a ton of these methods (`__add__`, `__trunc__`, `__floor__`, `__round__`, `__floordiv__`... I think 24 in total) and b) they all kinda follow the same pattern. That is, for any method, I probably just want:

```py
def __method__(self):
    return MyFloat(float.__method__(float(self))
```

or

```py
def __method__(self, other):
    return MyFloat(float.__method__(float(self), float(other)))
```

Is there a way to do what I want without manually implementing every math method (and repeating a ton of code)?

Keep in mind that `float.__method__` doesn't actually exist for every method. For example, `float.__floor__` doesn't exist, but I still need to implement `MyFloat.__floor__` to satisfy `numbers.Real` abstract base class.

Edit: Suggestions have been to extend `float` and that was also my first idea but I lose my "stickiness" requirement.  For example:

```py
>>> class MyFloat(float):
    def other_method(self):
        print("other method output")

>>> mf = MyFloat(8)
>>> mf.other_method()
other method output
>>> o = mf + 9
>>> type(o)
<class 'float'>
>>> o.other_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'other_method'
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to create a duplicate of an existing object type without manually implementing all of the methods?

Comment: You can do some trickery with either `__getattr__` or `exec` and string formatting in a loop.

Comment: @user1558604 no, I'm aware I could inherit from float, but I lose my "value" method and my "sticky" requirement. (afaik)
@MichaelButscher I ain't touching `exec` ;-)

Comment: If you want to subclass float, why not actually do that: `class MyFloat(float):` and then in the init function `super().__init__(value)`. That way all of the float class’s properties and methods are also in your class

Comment: If you extend float, you should be able to use all of its functions and add your own on top.

Comment: Regarding extending float, I'd like to, but I think I lose the stickiness I need.  I'm going to edit my question with an example.

Comment: An idea would be to write a method `__getattribute__` that would catch all method calls and analyze them to pass them on to the superclass in the way you suggested. But apparently that doesn’t work on methods that implement operators, like `__add__` which implements +. Decorators can be used instead, says https://stackoverflow.com/a/16372436/7840347

Comment: @JimDanner thanks for finding that. It has an accepted answer, but doing this still requires a bunch of manual work. Some methods are under `operator`, some under `math` and some on `float`. Somehow this doesn't have the clear elegance I was looking for, ya know? :-/

Comment: Classes are where Python loses its elegant simplicity :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is the most "elegant" solution I've come up with (even though it's hacks on hacks). If anyone has a suggestion for improvement I'm happy to select yours as the correct answer.

```py
import numbers
import math
import operator


def _operator_builder(numbers_base_cls, builtin_type):
    def _binary_method_builder(builtin_operator):
        def binary_method(a, b):
            if isinstance(b, numbers_base_cls):
                return type(a)(builtin_operator(builtin_type(a), builtin_type(b)))
            else:
                return NotImplemented

        binary_method.__name__ = '__' + builtin_operator.__name__ + '__'
        binary_method.__doc__ = operator.__doc__
        return binary_method

    def _monary_method_builder(builtin_operator):
        def monary_method(a, *args):
            return type(a)(builtin_operator(builtin_type(a), *args))

        monary_method.__name__ = '__' + builtin_operator.__name__ + '__'
        monary_method.__doc__ = operator.__doc__

        return monary_method
    return _binary_method_builder, _monary_method_builder


_float_binary_operator_helper, _float_monary_operator_helper = _operator_builder(numbers.Real, float)


class MyFloat(numbers.Real):
    __add__ = _float_binary_operator_helper(operator.add)
    __radd__ = __add__

    __trunc__ = _float_monary_operator_helper(math.trunc)
    __floor__ = _float_monary_operator_helper(math.floor)
    __ceil__ = _float_monary_operator_helper(math.ceil)
    __round__ = _float_monary_operator_helper(round)
    # etc... for all dunder methods

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = float(value)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = float(value)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.value
```

One improvement would be to define a list of (`name`, `func`) pairs and call `setattr(name, _float_monary_operator_helper(func))` on each of them during `__new__`.  However, I couldn't figure out how to do this and make ABC happy - it always complained that the methods weren't implemented.